# How to use python Maps on functions with more than one arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, functools

```
NAME_LIST = ["abc1","abc2","cde1"]
class abc:
    @staticmethod
    def foo(a,name,*args):
         a = do_something(name,*args)
         return do_another(a)
```

How to use python maps to pass in a list of names and print the output , when there is more than one function arguments

something like this, i want to keep a,*args as constants (but dont want to make it default arguments)

`list(map(abc.foo, NAME_LIST))`

I want to pass `NAME_LIST` variables into `name`

Comment: Take a look at `starmap`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap

Comment: What other arguments do you want to pass to `foo`? If there's aren't any, `map(abc.foo, NAME_LIST)` is fine. (`abc` here is an instance of the class, right, not the class itself?) Otherwise, you would be better off just defining a wrapper function that *does* take only one argument and mapping that over the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do:

```py
def myFunc(x,y, *args):
    return x*y+sum(args)

x=[[1,4,5,5,6,7], [3,2,1], [7,8], [2,9,0,4,3]]

y=list(map(lambda a: myFunc(*a), x))

y

#outputs:
[27, 7, 56, 25]
```

So in your case:

```py
NAME_LIST = ["abc1","abc2","cde1"]
class abc:
    @staticmethod
    def foo(a,name,*args):
         a = do_something(name,*args)
         return do_another(a)

list(map(lambda x: abc.foo(*x), [NAME_LIST]))
```

Just a note `map` iterates over provided iterable, so it will execute your function with EACH individual element of passed list, which if you keep it as `NAME_LIST` will be a single string each time - hence your function will fail, cause it has 2 positional arguments, so that's the minimum size of each element for the list you want to do `map` on - hence `[NAME_LIST]`.

Hope this makes sense!